# Error starting up Spring 4 with Jersey 2 JPA and Hibernate 5

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jersey

I am trying to start up a jersey-spring-jpa-hibernate app.   I am getting the following error

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator
May 05, 2017 2:51:19 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed here
```

However, when I look in my maven repository, I can see the class in the spring-tx jar :

```
 ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE/org/
springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator.class
```

I believe this may be due to problems in my pom file but I can not seem to track it down.

My pom file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kimproj</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-tunnel-anno</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>service-tunnel-anno</name>
    <properties>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1203-jdbc41</postgresql.version> 
        <jersey.version>2.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>service-tunnel-anno</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jersey-Spring http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3/2.4.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>       



        <!-- ******* JPA/Hibernate ******** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <!-- Jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>            
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/jta 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency--> 

</project>
```

My jpaContext.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean name="dataSource" id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"   value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName" />
        <property name="username" value="abc" />
        <property name="password" value="abc" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
             <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
     <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
         </props>
      </property> 

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (and not a ClassNotFoundException), it's probably some sort of classloading issue.

It's often caused by importing in the webapp librairies (WEB-INF/lib), JARs that are already available in the application server.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.  I had assumed since my classes were packed up into my war in my applications lib folder, that tomcat would load them.  When I added the path to the jar to my classpath, this error did go away.  Wondering if there is a tomcat configuration I missing that made me have to manually add the jar to my classpath.